# Knockout.js Project Structure

Tags: javascript, angularjs, knockout.js

I have been looking at Angular.js and Knockout.js as potential front end solutions. I love Knockout's tutorials and documentation. However, it is not clear to me how Knockout handles templating larger applications.

For example in Angular, you would make a main template like this:

```
<div id="content" class="container" ng-view></div>
```

And then this would be populated by by the "partials", for example:

```
<p>This is a partial</p>
```

My question is, does Knockout support the same concept? It appears that Knockout wants to use the "foreach" template (http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html). However, that does not address breaking the HTML down into smaller segments.

Am I on the right track here? Is there something I am missing in regards to Knockout's directory structure?

**EDIT:** I have gotten some good feedback. My understanding is that Knockout does not have a templating solution built in. If this is true, then I will probably need Angular.

Comment: With Knockout _you're_ in charge of app structure (just like in native JS development). Knockout solves data binding which helps a lot in structure of your UI layer in your application - but it leaves the structure of the rest of the application (routing, templating, partials, business logic structure) completely up to you - the question on "how to structure a web application" is very general, depends on your use cases and is out of the scope of SO.

Answer (score 11):

Knockout is not direct competition to the Angular framework, it is more like small library for data binding in MVVM style than full framework for building single page apps.

Please have a look at Durandal (http://durandaljs.com/), which is based on Knockout and provides composition based on recommended project structure and many other parts for successful implementation of single page apps (router, dialogs, tooling, build process, amd support etc...) similar to Angular or Ember.

Comment: +1 for discussing the different problem domains Knockout (Data binding and light MVVM, you having to structure your own code) and Angular (Whole framework) attempt to solve.

Comment: Good points. My intent was to use Bootstrap 3 and Snap.js in addition to some kind of front end framework. I figured Angular would be better for this, but the documentation is half baked compared to KO. Just getting over the learning curve has been a struggle.

Comment: @DiodeDan Have you seen egghead.io ?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I just looked at it. It may help!

Answer (score 2):

See Ryan Niemeyer's knockout AMD helpers [project on github](https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-amd-helpers)

From the Readme:

> This plugin is designed to be a lightweight and flexible solution to
>   working with AMD modules in Knockout.js. It provides two key features:
>
> 1- Augments the default template engine to allow it to load external
>   templates using the AMD loader's text plugin. This lets you create
>   your templates in individual HTML files and pull them in as needed by
>   name (ideally in production the templates are included in your
>   optimized file).
>
> 2- Creates a module binding that provides a flexible way to load data
>   from an AMD module and either bind it against a template or against an
>   anonymous/inline template.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want with sub templates, which can be treated as view partials.

For example:

```
<script type="text/html" id="main-template">

   some content...

   <!--ko template: {name: 'sub-template-1'} --><!-- /ko -->

   some more content...

   <!--ko template: {name: 'sub-template-2'} --><!-- /ko -->

</script>
```

And than you'll have to load the main template, like:

```
<!-- ko template: { name: 'main-template' } --><!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: Using script templates is no longer recommended in knockout. Don't use them. They recommend the use of Knockout’s native DOM-based templating (i.e., the foreach, if, with, etc. bindings) instead of jQuery.tmpl or any other string-based template engine. Also text.html is not a valid value for the attribute type

Comment: The type.html was a typo - I updated the post. While your statement may be right(I don't see anywhere on the KO Doc page saying that you should only use the native DOM based templating) I was just trying to show how to implement sub-templates with what KO.js can do - not another framework.

Comment: @XGreen Citation required, I can't find any mention of 'don't use script templates' in the documentation - mind elaborating?

Comment: @gabrielcatalin Thanks for pointing this out. Do you have a link to where you got this info? Are you referring to: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html?

Comment: This is how I use it in my own web app with KO 2.2.1. You won't actually find it in their documentation.

Comment: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html Look for this phrase in the page: Please note that, as of December 2011

Comment: script tags are for scripts thats why they are called script tags. they are not supposed to contain markup. There are flexible and powerful data bindings available so you can add behaviour to your markup.

Answer (score 0):

I didnt like the explicit template binding in KO, it was to much strings everywhere.
So I created a Convention over configuration library

Can be installed using nuget

```
Install-Package Knockout.BindingConventions
```

Lets say you have a member `this.selectedCustomer` on your model and that its content is of type `CustomerViewModel`. With my library this piece of html code

```
<div data-name="selectedCustomer"></div>
```

would bind the div to a template named "CustomerView"
http://jsfiddle.net/xJL7u/5/

It has a bunch of other conventions too for buttons, etc
https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/Knockout.BindingConventions/wiki

I also created a external template engine that uses above framework together they are really powerfull

```
Install-Package Knockout.Bootstrap
```

https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/Knockout.Bootstrap/wiki