# how to pre-compile templates with knockout?

Tags: templates, knockout.js

from the sample/tutorials of knockout, all view/templates are in one page, is it possible to separate them in different files and pre-compile them. just like what ember framework do.
if yes, is there a sample ? better using handlebars or knockout native template engine.

thanks.

Comment: see this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18538447/knockout-js-project-structure

Answer (score 2):

The guys from Cassette have found a solution to pre-compile Knockout JS templates: http://getcassette.net/documentation/v1/html-templates/knockoutjs-jquery-tmpl

But Cassette is an asset to build .NET web apps so this solution seems to work only for the .NET world.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different libraries for this, like

https://github.com/ifandelse/Knockout.js-External-Template-Engine

I have made my own too which uses a Convention approach

https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/Knockout.Bootstrap

```
Install-Package Knockout.Bootstrap
```

It needs a service to get the templates, once that is done you load templates like

```
this.bootstrap.loadView(model, this.view);
```

By convention if the model is sent in is named EditOrderViewModel it will load the View named EditOrderView

wiki
https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/Knockout.Bootstrap/wiki

Comment: thanks for your reply, but i want to pre-compiler all templates to a js file, and then the application can use them.
the lib/code what you list, it looks they are used to remote fetch the view html as template

Comment: I dont know if there is such a lib, didt find one when searching. If you're on VS you can create a t4 template that concats them. And then use a custom template source for knockout

Comment: One problem with your approach is that for large sites that JS file will be huge

Comment: But it would mean only one big request which is often better then several small ones and that file could be cached...

Comment: about my case, i just want to write a local web application ,using phonegap to wrapper it. so there is no server.
more specifically, i want to open it using file protocol: file::/path,

Comment: roughly checked ember framework. it can separate all templates into different files. and then pre-compile them into one js file. that is what i want. but ember is hard to study and it looks it is still under    development phase